# How does a C# Interface as a property work?

Tags: c#, oop, properties, interface

I am looking at the example from [Using SignalR in WinForms and WPF](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b/sourcecode?fileId=119892&pathId=583880341) in order to get an idea of how to implement SignalR in a .NET client application/dll. And I came across something that I don't get the concept of.

```
private IHubProxy HubProxy { get; set; }
```

When looking at the `IHubProxy` I can see that it is an interface. I have always understood that you could not make an instance of an interface but it was rather a contract for a new class if you implement it telling the new class what methods it has to implement.

How does an interface setup as a property work?

Comment: It means that anything that implements the IHubProxy can be set to that property, but it will be a concrete instance of something.  But all you care about is that it uses the IHubProxy contract as a consumer of that property and you don't care about the implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
Just to make sure that I understand this. The property HubProxy can hold an object/instance of a class that has the IHubProxy interface as part of the class definition. And by that I know that when I work with the object from the property that it does understand specific messages?

Comment: Yep unless it is null, it will absolutely provide some concrete behavior.

Comment: Okay got it. But how it this different from defining a property to be of a specific class? Lets say there is a class like this:
`public class HubProxy : IHubProxy`
What would be the effect of using this class instead of just the interface like this:
`public HubProxy hubProxy { get; set; }`

Comment: Because IHubProxy can be any implementation while HubProxy is one specific implementation. I would recommend reading up on dependency injection. The general idea is to not use specific implementation details except where it's necessary

Comment: _Dependency injection_ and _design pattern_ is now on my list of subjects to follow up on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can't make an instance for an **Interface** but you can make an instance of a class that implements that interface.

Let me make an example, consider the following code:

```
interface IEmailSender
{
   void SendEmail();
}

public class EmailSender : IEmailSender 
{
   public void SendEmail()
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   public void DoOtherStuff()
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Now the following code is perfectly legal:

```
IEmailSender mailSender = new EmailSender(); 
mailSender.SendEmail(); //Works just fine
mailSender.DoOtherStuff(); //Will raise an error at compile time
```

### Usage in a property

Let's build a test class:

```
public class Test 
{
    public IEmailSender MyEmailSender;
}
```

Now let's check the following code:

```
var testOBJ = new Test();
testOBJ.MyEmailSender = new IEmailSender(); //Raises a compile time error, as you outlined yourself
testOBJ.MyEmailSender = new EmailSender(); //Perfectly Legal
```

Basically **you can asign to that property anything that implements that interface**

Hope it's clear now :)

Comment: Got it. But I was wondering about using interfaces as a property instead of using an interface to a class definition.

Comment: @SoftAllan Check it out now :)

Comment: Excellent examples. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you can't make instances of an interface.

What that code means is that the HubProxy property is of a type that inhertis the IHubProxy interface. So for example, the get returns an instance of a class that implements the IHubProxy interface.